# Как продублировать значение с HTML страницы в вывод консоли Python?

Tags: html, python, парсер

Хочу получить актуальный курс EUR/USD с сайта [tradingview.com](https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/EURUSD/)

[image: EUR/USD]

[image: Code]

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/home/pc/geckodriver") # открывает новое окно браузера
driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/EURUSD/") # переходит по ссылке
res = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last") # ищет котировку
print(str(res)) # должно вывести котировку в консоль, но вместо этого - []
driver.quit() # закрывает окно браузера (браузер появляется в оконном режиме, а должен быть в консольном)
```

Как получить актуальную котировку с [данной страницы](https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/EURUSD/) сайта, используя Python?
Возможно ли это в связке, Python + JavaScript?

[image: Класс найден]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
url = "https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/EURUSD/"
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = bs(html, 'lxml') # 'html.parser' ничего не изменил
tags = soup.findAll("div", class_="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last")
print(tags)
```

Использую BeautifulSoup. По-прежнему не отображается содержимое класса

Comment: BeautifulSoup гораздо лучше подойдет.Зачем selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте так - задействовал и BeautifulSoup и Selenium

> driver.page_source возвращает фактический HTML-код, созданный браузером

```
python

>>> from selenium import webdriver

>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()#у Вас driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/home/pc/geckodriver")
>>> driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/EURUSD/")
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> pr = driver.page_source
>>> soup = bs(str(pr), 'lxml')
>>> tags = soup.findAll("div", class_="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last")
>>> print(tags)
[<div class="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last">1.0932<span class="tv-symbol-price-quote__value--falling"><sup>1</sup></span></div>]
```